# sampling points on an interpolated curve

Tags: python, time-series, sampling

I have this interpolated curve (black) using black data points. I used scipy.interpolate.griddata to obtain the curve, I was wondering if there's a way to sample function values from this interpolation at equispaced red (x,y) points such as the grid below.

[image: Curve]